# Мастер страница и Роуты в AngularJS. ASP.NET Core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь переписать свое приложение на AngularJS. Сам сайт простой, нет практический ничего кроме котроллеров которые возвращают вьюхи. Теперь архитертура немного другая. В стартапе я определяю начальную страницу. Она уже не cshmtl а просто html. Она запускается без проблем. 
Код стартапа где я убираю архитектуру МВС.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        }

        DefaultFilesOptions defoptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();

        var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

        defoptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        defoptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("app/pages/index/index.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(defoptions);

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                await next();
            }
        });


        //var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
        //app.UseRewriter(options);

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        //app.UseMvc(routes =>
        //{
        //    routes.MapRoute(
        //        name: "areas",
        //        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

        //    routes.MapRoute(
        //        name: "default",
        //        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //});
    }
```

Далее я создал приминитивный контроллерJS и модуль

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);


app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/Home', {
          templateUrl: 'app/pages/home/Home.html',
          controller: 'testController'
      });

});
```

Ну и сама страница Index которая нормально работает по умолчанию, но там есть хедер на котором просан роут(первый линк) как видете первая кнопка уже прописана как в роуте, но у меня нет перехода, получаю что такой страницы не существует. Как я только не писал. #! и # как угодно, роуты не пашут, может класс стартап я неправильно переопределяю? или каких-то библеотек не подключил?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

```
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/angularjs.js"></script>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" 
    <script 


 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"> 
  </script>
    <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular- 
   route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <div ng-include="'/app/pages/header/header.html'"></div>



</header>
<div ng-view></div>
```

страница хедера где ссылка на другую страницу. Первый линк /Home

```
                <ul style="margin-left:140px;" class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="/Home" class="nav-link">страница</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp- 
    action="Education" class="nav-link">страница</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp- 
 action="MyStory" class="nav-link">страница</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-a 
   ction="Story" class="nav-link">страница</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp- 
     action="Contacts" class="nav-link">Страница</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp- 
     action="Blog" class="nav-link">Блог</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp- 
        action="Traders" class="nav-link">Трейдерам</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```